# constructor that will accept unknown number of variables of different types

Tags: java

Is it possible to create a single constructor that will accept unknown number of variables of different types?

I need something like:

```
A a=new A("a",1.1,"b",2.2,"c"3.3....);
```

I know that I can define the following:

```
class A{
   public A(String... args){}
}
```

but this constructor receives only strings

Comment: They only way is: `public A(Object... args)`

Comment: Ditto it's the only solution, but it looks like an XY problem. You won't know what these types are and will be able to do little aside from treating them as `Object`s.

Comment: You want to use `Object` because your data look like mixed `integer, float, String`